# Delete description and id from multiple selected choice

Tags: javascript, backspace

I have a multiselect list where on double click of an item I am appending the description and id to respective separate strings.
finally it would be like
string description = "desc1,desc2,desc3";
string ids="id1,id2,id3";
these description and id's are placed in an input box.now my requirement is to delete any of the choice which is already selected by pressing the backspace key on the input box.

[image]

For an example if user wants to remove 'Wood 44*44' from description then it should remove the description as well as its corresponding id as well.how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: please explain your question...and what you have tried

Comment: please share your code here..

Comment: i am looking for an suggestion to delete the description when the user enters backspace.I may not require the full code here.but expert idea could guide me on how to approach.I am thinking about the difficulties when the user put the pointer in between the string and starts to delete.